# Meteor ironrouter - A collection returns undefined even though I am calling waitOn()

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Update: This has been solved and the code amended to reflect the changes I added. I also strongly recommend reading the comment below this post. Some changes are coming in IronRouter we need to be mindful of.

The crucial thing is to add the following to your data function:

```
if(!this.ready()) {
    return;
}
```

I am having an issue with IronRouter in my application. The code is below:

```
/** 
 *  Project list view (all projects) with optional 
 *  filter parameter for showing projects only by 
 *  their category name.
 */ 
this.route('list', {
    path: '/:_category_slug?',
    template: 'template_main',
    action: function() {
        if(this.ready()) {
            this.render();
        }
    },
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('projects'), 
            Meteor.subscribe('formations'),
            Meteor.subscribe('categories')
        ];
    },
    data: function() {
        if(!this.ready()) {
            return;
        }

        if(this.params._category_slug) {
            /**
             * Building up the query given the category slug and the language
             */
            var query = {};
            query['slug.' + App.language] = this.params._category_slug;

            /**
             *  Grab the category given the query
             */
            var category = App.models.categories.findOne(query);

            console.log(category);

            return App.models.projects.find({}).fetch();

        }
        else {
            return App.models.projects.find({}).fetch();
        }
    },
    yieldTemplates: {
        'components_header': {to: 'header'},
        'views_list': {to: 'content'},
        'components_footer': {to: 'footer'}
    }
});
```

What I am trying to do is get the category from the category slug so I can access its ID, which I need for another query.

The problem is, when I reload the page and the path given above is matched, this route seems to be run three times, and the first time, logging the category variable on the console returns undefined, and then another two times, the actual category is printed out.

I would expect that the waitOn() function would have populated all categories by the time I reach the data function, so I can access my category data with the query the first time around, but this is not happening.

Can anyone see anything glaringly obvious in my code that could be causing this issue, and why is the route being run three times?

I am using the latest version of IronRouter (iron:router@0.9.3) and Meteor (METEOR@0.9.2.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `iron:router` <= 0.9.3 you have to activate the default `loading` hook in order to get the expected behavior of WAITING for the subscriptions to be ready before rendering the templates.

Add this in your router configuration code :

```
Router.onBeforeAction("loading");
```

This means you no longer have to provide an `action` function doing the waiting logic (rendering your templates only when the `WaitList` is ready).

However, the `data` function will still get called initially when subscriptions are not ready, so you have to do the check yourself :

```
data:function(){
  if(!this.ready()){
    return;
  }
  // return actual data when ready
}
```

A lot of questions about `iron:router` have surfaced regarding this `loading` hook behavior, and to be fair it's true that it is catchy because when you use `waitOn`, you expect your `RouteController` to actually WAIT ON those subscriptions before displaying templates, right ?

This is why in the latest "unstable" release of `iron:router@1.0.0-pre2`, the `loading` hook is automatically added for you when it detects you're using `waitOn`.

I strongly advise you to switch to `iron:router@1.0.0-pre2` to get familiar with the newest API, it features a complete rewrite and nice docs which are up-to-date.

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md

It is mostly backward compatible with a few gotchas, notably it requires you to define all your routes along with `RouteController`s in the `lib/` folder so that it is available to both the client and server.

Comment: Thank you for your very quick answer. This has solved the problem.

Comment: Added some comments regarding the very latest version of `iron:router`.

Comment: Hi, that link to github is 404ing at the moment :( I was looking forward to reading it haha :)